# How do I visualize a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, visualisation

*Preferred software use: ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online*

For a client I have to visualize a building plan that has a 'many-to-many'-link with attribute data. As with many-to-many relationships; sometimes an attribute applies to multiple rooms, and rooms themselves are in most cases linked to multiple attributes.

For this I want to create an attractive visualization. Preferably a bit like this:

The screen is split in half, the left is the list of attributes. Clicking on one attribute will make a change in the map on the right, where only the rooms will lighten up that apply to this attribute. Clicking in the map will make a selection on the list on the left side. Showing only the affected attributes for that specific room.

[image: Example of what is should look like]

I'm not sure if this is possible in ArcGIS Online WebAppDeveloper at the moment. There are many widgets, but my knowledge about these tools is currently very limited.

Comment: Do you have this working with a simple example?  e.g. click on an attribute and highlight on the map? That may be a good place to start.

Comment: In ArcGIS Online I can construct interactive hyperlinks (Story Map mode) which make it possible to switch between layers in the map on the right. This is a start. However clicking on the map on the right will always open up only a very small (5x5 cm / 2x2inch) box. Which is not suitable for all the attributes I have (in some cases over 100 )